# how do i send data to the client using expressJS without overwriting the content that's already on the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, routes

So I am building a SPA using MySQL, ExpressJS, ReactJS, and NodeJS. The client side has multiple different routes, but all rendered using reactJS as a SPA.

I have a / route, a /admin route, and a /tickets route

currently I am struggling with the /tickets route, I do not know how to send the contents of my database to the /tickets route without overwriting the data that is already rendered in that route in reactJS.

for example my reactJS file for this route looks like this in its most basic sense:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
//The ticketing system page, here the mySQL table will display a list of all active tickets to the admins and IT staff
function TicketingSystem(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <h5>{expressJSData}</h5>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TicketingSystem;
```

and my server code looks like this:

```
app.get('/tickets', (req, res) => {
    res.send('a new ticket has appeared!');
});
```

I am oversimplifying it, but when i send that data it overwrites my Hello World text. I'd like it to appear under hello world in place of the expressJSData variable / placeholder that I have set.

Is this possible? I feel like it should be but it's just escaping me right now, I have absolutely no clue how to go about it.

Comment: Can you share the rendering code where you are using the TicketingSystem component?